# Get value type Enum from Model working DropDownChoice and SelectOption

Tags: java, wicket

I can not get the Enum type value of a DropDownChoice that is linked to a SelectOption[] class, I see that the object has the expected value but I have no idea how to get it in my model.

Initially the DropDownChoice worked with the values defined in the model, and it works well, but I need to show the detail of each value, there I was stuck

```
@Entity
public class Asegurado extends EntityBase {
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Genero genero = Genero.M;

public static enum Genero {
    M, F, D
}

public Genero getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(Genero genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}
```

}

The selectOption is:

```
public class SelectOption implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Enum<?> name;
private String value;

public SelectOption(Enum<?> name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}   

public Enum<?> getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(Enum<?> name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}
```

}

In Application Bean:

```
SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {
    new SelectOption(Genero.M, "Masculino"), 
    new SelectOption(Genero.F, "Femenino"),
    new SelectOption(Genero.D, "Diferenciado")
    };
Asegurado wase = new Asegurado();
ChoiceRenderer<Enum> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<Enum>("value", "name");
    final DropDownChoice<Asegurado.Genero> generoWk = new DropDownChoice(
            "genero",
            new Model<Asegurado.Genero>(Asegurado.Genero.D),
            Arrays.asList(options),
            choiceRenderer
            );
```

In onSubmit() the problem is in:

```
asegurado.setGenero(generoWk.getModelObject());
```

The error: "Cannot be cast"

Please Help.

Comment: `new DropDownChoice(` <- It looks like you are using a raw-type. You should rather use `new DropDownChoice<>(` or `new DropDownChoice<Asegurado.Genero>(` for better type safety. I suppose if you did that it would tell you that your Choicerenderer is not a valid option as I am pretty sure it should be a `ChoiceRenderer<Asegurado.Genero>` and not just refering to the basic `Enum`  type.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I switched to ChoiceRenderer <Asegurado.Genero> but to change new DropDownChoice <Asegurado.Genero> the error "is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

When I run Debug, I realize that the DropDownChoice loads correctly:

```
generoWK=DropDownChoice<T>
data=Model<T>
Object=Asegurado$Genero
name="D"
```

When I execute the onSubmit() it changes:

```
val$generoWK=DropDownChoice<T>
data=Model<T>
Object=SelectOptions
name=Asegurado$Genero
name="D"
```

Something causes the variable to be modified, I do not know what, but I'm interested in getting the name = "D" value as an enum type